# How to size a refrigeration compressor based on an evaporator size?

Tags: thermodynamics, refrigeration

I purchased an evaporator holding the following specifications:
Cooling Capacity = 2 kW
Size = 66 X 53 X 43
What I need to know is how to choose a compressor just to gain this full cooling capacity?

Comment: This looks like a "[homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832)" (note the quotation marks, follow the link and read the answer given there). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: @Wasabi, I think it may just be a cart-before-the-horse issue. Sometimes you don't know what you don't know ;-)

Comment: Please provide more information on what you are trying to cool, how many watts of cooling you need, and more info on your evaporator like a photo or something.

Answer (score 5):

When designing a refrigeration system, the first thing you need to know is the temperature you wish to heat/cool something to and the temperature of the source/sink you are pumping to or from.

You can use the [Carnot Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot%27s_theorem_(thermodynamics)) to solve for your theoretical best efficiency.

Once you know that, you deturmine what capacity you need. Like 2kW for example if I know I need to cool a 2kW laser, or 100W if I know I need to cool a 100W processor. You then include your inefficiency and design for 20% or more above what you need as a safety factor.

From that point, you can go on to sizing your compressor, working fluid, operating pressure, condenser, evaporator, air flow rates, etc. Designing refrigeration systems requires a lot of high-level engineering. I recommend investigating your original objective, researching refrigeration systems, and posting back here with a new question if you need help at that point.